# Phalcon framework, can't get data from modal to controller

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

```
public function searchStudent($student)
{

    $db = Di::getDefault()->get('db');

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM students WHERE insurance_number = "'.$student['searchInsurenceNum'].'"';

    $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
```

When i check here die(var_dump($sth->fetchAll())), i am getting array with data from database.

```
    return $sth->fetchAll();
}


public function searchAction()
{
    $request = new Request();
    $response = new Response();

    if ($request->isPost()) {
       (new ContactsStorage())->searchStudent($request->getPost());
    }
```

But in controller when i call fuction die(var_dump((new ContactsStorage())->searchStudent())), i am getting empty array .

```
    $this->view->setVar('findData', (new ContactsStorage())->searchStudent());

}
```

Comment: Did you forget to pass a parameter in `searchStudent()` (in your controller)?

Comment: Why not use models ? Also why you don't access request and response like `$this->request` and `$this->response` ? Please read some docs before using anything :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your request is not a POST ? (`$request->isPost()`)
by using this method you're allow to find your students only on POST request. Remove condition and try again.

If you have model `Student` which extends `\Phalcon\Mvc\Model` you can use magic static methods `findBy{$FeildCamelCasedName}` so there is no need to create extra repositories and even methods if you want to ge tsome entity by simple criteria:

`$findData = Student::findByInsuranceNumber($in);`

also you can find one element by such criteria by simply using magic method `findFirstBy{$Field}`